# Force top level of ExpandableListView to be at top of list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

We have an ExpandableListView with a good number of parent and child entries.

When one "parent" is opened we automatically close the previously open group so that only one group is open at any one top.
However, we would like the group to appear at the current top of the visible data.
In other words, the "parent" should be the first visible in the list with the children following.

What is actually happening is that it is opening it correctly but it is positioned randomly. In most cases the top visible line is actually one of the children and we have to scroll back to get to the parent entry.

Is there some way to force what should be shown as the top line in the view.

Comment: Not quite clear... do you want the open parent at the top of the expandable list, or do you want group line that is open at the top of the screen when opened (they are *not* the same thing).

Comment: I want the group line (the "header" of the group) to be at the top of the screen when opened. At the moment it is "above" the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after much struggling we managed to find a solution:

```
categoryListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {

            categoryListView.setSelectionFromTop(groupPosition, 0);
            Boolean shouldExpand = (!categoryListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition));
            categoryListView.collapseGroup(lastClickedPosition);
            if (shouldExpand){
                categoryListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            }                
            lastClickedPosition = groupPosition;

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is not working when the expanded group is below collapsed group. It scroll to the end or middle of the child items.